# Highlight specific columns in grid.table/tableGrob in R

Tags: r, gridextra, r-grid

I want to highlight specific columns of a table to a different colour.

This is how the table appears now, when I use grid.table to save it as an image.

[image]

I want the RMSE and MAPE columns to be highlighted, thus should be of different colours, say yellow.

I am using the following code for the same but only the column heads are getting highlighted, not the data.

```
cols <- c("grey90","grey90", "yellow", "grey90","grey90", "yellow", "grey90",
          "grey90", "grey90", "grey90")
t1 <- ttheme_default(
  core=list(bg_params = list(col=cols)),
  colhead=list(bg_params = list(fill=cols)))
```

This is how the table looks after that.

[image]

Comment: it is useful to put the required packages to run the code

Comment: Sorry. These functions were from the grid and gridExtra packages

Answer (score 0):

When passing a vector of colours it needs to be either of the same length as the total number of elements (18), or shorter/longer but in this case its first nrow elements will be recycled columnwise.

```
library(gridExtra)

cols <- c("grey90","yellow", "green")
t1 <- ttheme_default(
  core=list(bg_params = list(fill=cols)))

d <- data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(18)),2,9))
names(d) <- letters[1:9]
grid.newpage()
grid.table(d, theme=t1)
```

Comment: In this case the entire row gets highlighted. I want the columns to be highlighted. I guess core works rowwise. Is there anyway I can make it work columnwise.

Comment: Found a way in this answer. You should make cols into a matrix as it is read columnwise. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974476/customizing-font-colour-of-one-column-for-a-tablegrob-in-r/38975305#38975305